# cmake add_custom_command dependent on object library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to generate a version file using cmake using `add_custom_command`. I only want the version file to be (re)generated if another target (an object library) had any changes.

Here is my current simplified CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project (version-test)

# Object file compilation target.
add_library(version-test-objects OBJECT main.cpp)

# Version object file target.
add_custom_command(OUTPUT version.cpp
    COMMAND date "+char const *getVersion\\\(\\\) { return \\\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\\"\; }"
    > version.cpp
    DEPENDS version-test-objects
)
add_library(version-test-version OBJECT
    version.cpp
)

# Binary target.
add_executable(version-test
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:version-test-objects>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:version-test-version>
)
```

And for completeness my simplified main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

extern char const *getVersion();

int main() {
    std::cout << getVersion() << std::endl;
}
```

The `version.cpp` is generated fine along with the first build. However, changes to the source (e.g., `touch main.cpp`) only rebuilds `version-test-objects` and links the executable, without regenerating `version.cpp`.

How can I get cmake to regenerate `version.cpp` if and only if `version-test-objects` had any changes?

Comment: I guess the file is regenerated but with the same timestamp. Check the creation data of `version.cpp` after changing `version-test-objects`. The `VERSION` cmake variable I think is stored in the cache - it will be set upon cmake configuration, and not change later. Btw the `> version.cpp` is parsed by shell, so it's kind of pointless assuming you have posix shell redirection but no `echo` builtin (cause you are using `cmake -E echo`).

Comment: @KamilCuk Indeed, the cmake variable is not updated. However, cmake spits out a `Generating version.cpp` message, and that only appears during the first build, not when there were changes to `version-test-objects` thereafter. The system timestamp of `version.cpp` also indicates that it was not regenerated.

Comment: So you need to move the timestamp creation to add_custom_command. Btw. why not use `return __DATE__ " " __TIME__` in this simple case? Or your target case is more complex? So you have to move it all inside `add_custom_command`, otherwise it will be generated only once, during configuration. Or you could re-configure cmake with each compilation.

Comment: @KamilCuk This is all very much simplified code for posting here. The actual command actually gets git version information.

Comment: Well, you could move getting git version into a cmake script and invoke cmake script from inside add_custom_command with `cmake -P`... But that looks like a workaround. I would go with a simple `COMMAND git rev-parse HEAD | xargs printf "const char *getVersion() { return \"%s\"; }" > version.cpp`

Comment: @KamilCuk Getting the command to work isn't the issue, it's getting the command to run when there were changes to the `version-test-objects` library.

Comment: @KamilCuk I've updated the command in the question to use `date` to generate unique file contents every time it is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DEPENDS version-test-objects` only specifies a target level dependency meaning that this command potentially gets run after building the target `version-test-objects`.  You stated the requirement that the command should run whenever any object file part of `version-test-objects` gets updated.  So those also have to be listed in `DEPENDS` as well.  This could be considered a bug regarding the differences between OBJECT libraries and normal libraries.

```
# Version object file target.
add_custom_command(OUTPUT version.cpp
    COMMAND date "+char const *getVersion\\\(\\\) { return \\\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\\"\; }"
    > version.cpp
    DEPENDS version-test-objects $<TARGET_OBJECTS:version-test-objects>
)
```

This works for me using CMake 3.13 Makefile generator.  This may not work in versions CMake 3.8 or earlier as the release notes state that this expression wasn't added until 3.9.  If that is the case you probably need to create a dummy archive that uses all the objects and then use that as a dependency.